# Data extraction from text file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a text file in the following format:-

```
$DATA1 SOURCE='HSPICE' VERSION='I-2013.12-SP2-1 32-BIT'  
.TITLE 'cmos inverter transfer characteristics'  
index            t_r              t_f              t_rf              
                 t_fr             t_rr             t_ff              
                 temper           alter#            
1                 1.361e-11        1.177e-11        8.807e-12        
                  9.063e-12        2.002e-08        2.002e-08        
                  2.500e+01       1                 
2                 1.339e-11        1.178e-11        8.805e-12        
                  8.867e-12        2.002e-08        2.002e-08        
                  2.500e+01       1                 
3                 1.334e-11        1.177e-11        8.811e-12        
                  8.824e-12        2.002e-08        2.002e-08        
                  2.500e+01       1   

.  
.  
.  
1000 1.339e-11        1.178e-11        8.805e-12        
                  8.867e-12        2.002e-08        2.002e-08        
                  2.500e+01       1
```

I wish to remove first 5 lines and extract the 9 numerical values from set of three lines, all in 9 different output files using awk command.
example of output file is:-
File1.txt

```
1  
2  
3  
.  
.  
1000
```

file2.txt

```
1.361e-11   
1.339e-11   
1.334e-11  
.  
.  
.  
1.339e-11
```

same for all the nine elements in a set of three lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure `awk` solution:

```
awk '
  NR<=5 { next }
  { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i > "File"++c}
  NF==2 { c=0 }
'
```

It skippes five lines of header, prints the fields on the remaining data in files with names defined by a counter, which is reset on lines with only two fields.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in bare `awk`, but first what comes to my mind is `sed`+`awk` combo:

```
sed '1,5d;s/^\([[:digit:]]\)/\n\1/' file | 
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i > "file"i".txt"}}'
```

The point is to add (with `sed`) new line to all lines which start from *digit*, and after that redefine record separator in `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another `sed` plus `tr` plus `printf`:

```
tr -s '[:space:]' \\n <infile |
sed "/^[0-9]/,${$(
    printf '\nw file%b\nn' \
           1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 '9\n}\c'
)"
```

I ran it on my clipboard as piped out by `xsel` in `/tmp` after copying your example to the buffer and afterwards did...

```
head -n3 /tmp/file?
```

...which printed...

```
==> /tmp/file1 <==
1
2
3

==> /tmp/file2 <==
1.361e-11
1.339e-11
1.334e-11

==> /tmp/file3 <==
1.177e-11
1.178e-11
1.177e-11

==> /tmp/file4 <==
8.807e-12
8.805e-12
8.811e-12

==> /tmp/file5 <==
9.063e-12
8.867e-12
8.824e-12

==> /tmp/file6 <==
2.002e-08
2.002e-08
2.002e-08

==> /tmp/file7 <==
2.002e-08
2.002e-08
2.002e-08

==> /tmp/file8 <==
2.500e+01
2.500e+01
2.500e+01

==> /tmp/file9 <==
1
1
1
```